# combining split functions and count occurrences in python

Tags: python, string, list, split

I create a list with:

```
import os
files=[f for f in os.listdir(source) if f.endswith('.tif')]
```

sometimes this gives a result like:

```
files=['file_1263_1-001.tif', 'file_1263_2-002.tif', 'file_1263_3-003.tif']

for f in files:
  l1 = f.split("_")
  print( l1[2].split("-") )
```

returns:

```
['1', '001.tif']
['2', '002.tif']
['3', '003.tif']
```

but sometimes I get this result:

```
files=['file_0563_74-001.tif', 'file_0563_74-002.tif', 'file_0563_74-003.tif']

for f in files:
  l1 = f.split("_")
  print( l1[2].split("-") )
```

returns:

```
['74', '001.tif']
['74', '002.tif']
['74', '003.tif']
```

I would like to create a flow control that if the first column (e.a. 74) has the same values, do someting else than when it contains different values (e.a. 1, 2, 3).
How do I accomplish that?

Comment: By using an `if` statement?

Comment: I guess if is the best to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a set comprehension to extract unique types. Then use an `if` / `else` construct to apply logic depending on whether you have only one such type.

```
files = ['file_1263_1-001.tif', 'file_1263_2-002.tif', 'file_1263_3-003.tif']

file_types = {fn.split('-')[0].rsplit('_')[-1] for fn in files}

if len(file_types) == 1:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Do in this way:

```
files = [f.split('_')[2].split('-') for f in files]
files
Output: [['1', '001.tif'], ['2', '002.tif'], ['3', '003.tif']]
```

Check if all first elements are same. If same then length of unique elements will be 1

```
if len(set([x[1] for x in files])) == 1:  # checks first elements are same
    # do something
else:
    # do something
```